# Merging 2 lists into a third but in pairs

Tags: prolog

I want, given 2 lists, to merge them into a third one but each element of the third list is a list of the first and second list's elements.

E.g. given the list1 `[1,2,3]` and list2 `[1,2,3]` I want the final list to be `[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]`

What I've done so far is

```
merge([],[],Z).
merge([H1|T1],[T2|T2],Z):-
    append([H1],[H2],W),merge(T1,T2,[W,Z]).
```

but I get a False result. Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some flaws in your code:

- when the first two lists are empty, the result must be an empty list too;
- Instead of `[T2|T2]` you should write `[H2|T2]` to represent the second list;
- there is no need to use `append([H1],[H2],W)` to create a list with two elements, just write `[H1,H2]`;
- since the recursive call must merge the tails of the first and second lists, there is no way the result of this call to be a list starting with the element `[H1,H2]`.

Thus, a correct definition for that predicate is as follows:

```
my_merge([], [], []).
my_merge([H1|T1], [H2|T2], [[H1,H2]|T3]):-
    my_merge(T1, T2, T3).
```

Examples:

```
?- my_merge([a,b,c], [1,2,3], L3).
L3 = [[a, 1], [b, 2], [c, 3]].

?- my_merge(L1, L2, [[1,a],[2,b],[3,c]]).
L1 = [1, 2, 3],
L2 = [a, b, c].
```

**Remark** Consider the possibility of representing the pair `[H1,H2]` as `H1-H2`, as the latter representation is more commonly used in Prolog.